# Plotly.express: How to make points animate consistently (grow-up) over the data frame, without vanishing the already spawned points?

Tags: python, plotly, visualization

I'm currently visualizing the data of "Bombing areas during the Vietnam War".

Here is the data:

```
DATE       |   TARGET_LATITUDE    |  TARGET_LONGTITUDE
1/10/1969  |    10.469393         |  106.019629
1/10/1969  |    11.525273         |  107.06769
1/10/1969  |    10.973675         |  106.019629
...
1/10/1970  |    11.469921         |  105.918000 
1/10/1970  |    12.589493         |  103.019346
...
1/10/1972  |    10.464893         |  103.013245
...
```

My idea is to visualize this data with Plotly.

More specifically, I want the bombed points to appear gradually over time without disappearing the points that appeared in the previous frame.

I have used `animation_frame` parameter in `scatter_mapbox`, however, the result was not as expected. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
data = pd.read_csv("./data/THOR_Vietnam_Bombing_Operations.csv", 
                   encoding="latin-1", 
                   usecols=["DATE", "TARGET_LATITUDE", "TARGET_LONGTITUDE", "AIRCRAFT_ORIGINAL"])
data = data.sort_values(["MSNDATE"])
# Use first 2000 data: 1966 - 1970
data = data.iloc[:2000]
fig = px.scatter_mapbox(data, lat="TARGET_LATITUDE", 
                        lon="TARGET_LONGTITUDE", 
                        animation_frame="DATE",
                        animation_group="TARGET_LONGTITUDE", 
                        color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Hot, 
                        color_discrete_sequence=["red"])
fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="carto-positron")
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.update_layout(autosize=False, width=600, height=750)
fig.show()
```

It works, however, I want the "**existed** bombed points" still on the map.

Is there any possible way to solve this? Thank you for help!

Here is the current result:

[image: current_result]

Example of expected result:

[image: expected_result]

Comment: post the data and not an image of the data. Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, which text allows for and pictures do not.
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The code you shared is missing a lot of parts. Please include a **working** example (you are missing imports and the generation of the `data` variable). We cannot help you otherwise.

Comment: @D.L Yes sir, I have modified the question!

Comment: a great explanation:  so the solution should be relatively straight forward.  If you want to retain the data, then store all the points to a **total** list and plot this list...

Comment: This cannot be achieved with express, so it must be created with a graph object. Each animation frame would need to be extracted to include all previous data. A sample graph object can be found [here](https://plotly.com/python/animations/#using-a-slider-and-buttons).